# Postback script not working

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, postback, autopostback

I am running a CPA site and needs instant tracking of offers completed by my users through my site but the postback script I am using is not working it is not changing the value of amount in my database. Below is the script:

```
<?php 

$dbhost = 'host';
$dbuser = 'user';
$dbpass = 'pass';
$dbname = 'name';

// 2. Create a database connection
$connection = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

// 3. Select a database to use 
$db_select = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connection);
if (!$db_select) {
    die("Database selection failed: " . mysql_error());
}

$subid = $_REQUEST['subid'];
$amount = $_REQUEST['payout'];

mysql_query("UPDATE users SET amount=amount+".$amount." WHERE id='".$subid."'");

   echo "<b>Amount Credited:</b> Rs ".$amount.";      

?>
```

Comment: just be aware of [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: please help since i am a newbie to php what changes should i do to my script

Comment: Please read the link I post in my previous comment. And update your question and add your javascript as well.